# Trouble binding to property in uwp MVVM project

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, xbind

I am having a problem with binding from a view to a Viewmodel property.(UWP)

```
<AppBarToggleButton Label="Active" Icon="People"
                                    IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsStatusBtnChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.empStautsBtnClicked}"/>

private bool isStatusBtnChecked = true;

    public bool IsStatusBtnChecked
    {
        get { return isStatusBtnChecked; }
        set { Set(ref isStatusBtnChecked, value); }
    }
```

When I try to get the value from a method to load combobox items the value is allways the default value

```
private List<string> depcombo;

    public List<string> Depcombo
    {
        get { return depcombo; }
        set
        {
            if (depcombo != value)
            {
                depcombo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Depcombo");
            }
        }
    }
    public async void GetDepCombo()
    {
        List<string> _dep = new List<string>();
        var data2 = await SqlServerDataService.GetAllEmployeesAsync();
        var depResult = (from emp in EmpItems
                         where emp.Status == IsStatusBtnChecked
                         select emp.Department).Distinct();
        foreach (var item in depResult)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                _dep.Add(item);
            }
        }
        Depcombo = _dep;
    }
```

When I load the data for Employyes it works fine

```
 public async Task LoadDataAsync(MasterDetailsViewState viewState)
    {
        EmpItems.Clear();
        var data = await SqlServerDataService.GetAllEmployeesAsync();
        data.Where(em => em.Status == IsStatusBtnChecked).ToList().ForEach(p => EmpItems.Add(p));
        if (viewState == MasterDetailsViewState.Both)
        {
            Selected = EmpItems.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Some help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to get the value from a method to load combobox items the value is allways the default value

It's is confused that which is the combobox `ItemsSource`, if `Depcombo` is ComboBox `ItemsSource`, You have passed a new list instance to `ItemsSource` when you call `GetDepCombo` method.

```
Depcombo = _dep;
```

So, we need to set bind mode as `OneWay`(OneTime is default) that could response the object instance change.

```
<ComboBox
    Margin="0,120,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainViewModel.Depcombo, Mode=OneWay}"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If `EmpItems` is ComboBox `ItemsSource`, and it is [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) type. When you call `LoadDataAsync`, EmpItems clear the items fist, then add the new items. And this processing does not change the `EmpItems` instance object. it could works in onetime mode.

```
<ComboBox Margin="0,120,0,0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainViewModel.EmpItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>


<AppBarToggleButton Label="Active" Icon="People"
                                            x:Name="empStatusBtn"
                                            IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsStatusBtnChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.empStautsBtnClicked}"/>

public async void empStautsBtnClicked()
    {
        await LoadDataAsync(MasterDetailsViewState.Both);
    }
```

Looks like the problem is when the view is reloaded. Is there a way to refresh the view without reloading. When reloading the value of

```
private bool isStatusBtnChecked = true;

    public bool IsStatusBtnChecked
    {
        get { return isStatusBtnChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (isStatusBtnChecked != value)
            {
                isStatusBtnChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsStatusBtnChecked");
            }
        }
    }
```

is true but the button isChecked property is false;

Comment: If  you want to keep the button state, you could store `isStatusBtnChecked` property into app's  [`LocalSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-18362)before reload page . and load the value after the page loaded.